# Twig, add first and last class

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Let's say I have a for loop like this:

```
{% for elem in arrMenu %}
    <div class="topmenu-button">
        <a href="{{ elem.url }}">{{ elem.name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In that form, it would render something like:

```
<div class="topmenu-button"><a href="url">name</a></div>
<div class="topmenu-button"><a href="url">name</a></div>
<div class="topmenu-button"><a href="url">name</a></div>
<div class="topmenu-button"><a href="url">name</a></div>
```

How can twig help me to add first and last classes the the div, so that I would have a result like:

```
<div class="topmenu-button first"><a href="url">name</a></div>
<div class="topmenu-button"><a href="url">name</a></div>
<div class="topmenu-button"><a href="url">name</a></div>
<div class="topmenu-button last"><a href="url">name</a></div>
```

Comment: You could use `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudoclasses. Those are wildly supported these days.

Comment: You could also use [IE7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to add support for CSS3 to some legacy IE.

Comment: Just a quick note; I just corrected a mistake where I had inverted the for parameters.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use the "special variables" `loop.first` and `loop.last` for what you want.

[LINK](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)

```
{% for elem in arrMenu %}
    {% if loop.first %}
    <div class="topmenu-button first">        
    {% elseif loop.last %}
    <div class="topmenu-button last">        
    {% else %}
    <div class="topmenu-button">        
    {% endif %}
        <a href="{{ elem.url }}">{{ elem.name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT: depending how much you care about the "one case", you might need a solution like this.

```
{% for elem in arrMenu %}
    {% set classes = ["topmenu-button"] %}
    {% if loop.first %}{% set classes = classes|merge(["first"]) %}{% endif %}
    {% if loop.last %}{% set classes = classes|merge(["last"]) %}{% endif %}
    <div class="{{ classes|join(" ") }}">        
        <a href="{{ elem.url }}">{{ elem.name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe i am wrong, i'm quite new to Twig, but if the array contains just one element the `if` statements will be both executed, resulting in `class="topmenu-button first last`. In this case you should use `if...else`. But as i said, i might be wrong.

Comment: In general, we can also use something like this: <div class="topmenu-button {{ loop.last ? 'last' }} ">

Answer (score 10):

Since a loop can't be `first` and `last` at the same time, i would prefer not to use `elseif` and write (DRY - what if you have to change `topmenu-button` in future?):

```
{% for elem in arrMenu %}
    {% set append %}
        {% if loop.first %}first{% endif %}
        {% if loop.last %}last{% endif %}
    {% endset %}
    <div class="topmenu-button {{ append }}">
        <a href="{{ elem.url }}">{{ elem.name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

or more concise:

```
{% for elem in arrMenu %}
    <div class="topmenu-button {% if loop.first %}first{% endif %} {% if loop.last %}last{% endif %}">
        <a href="{{ elem.url }}">{{ elem.name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**: this way you'll get some extra spaces in `class` attribute (it's perfectly fine btw).
**Edit2**: this will not handle 1-element array (first = last)

Comment: I used to try and code HTML (and twig) like this, but honestly your "more concise" solution looks a lot more line noisy, and the previous example has more code to set the variable than the main body of the `<div>` your printing. A tempting language like TWIG isn't really suited for perfect conformance to DRY since all "code" has to be escaped by `{%`/`%}`.

Comment: @KendallHopkins I agree what you say about concise code, i will always use the first one. IMHO it's better to write more code to set the variable instead of repeat the `div` declaration and `class` attribute 3 times. With tons of repetition like yours changing something will be really a pain (and a waste of time and money). Plus `elseif` and `else` looks horrible to me.

Comment: After looking at this problem again, I think we're both wrong. We're forgetting the "one" case, where you can have `class="topmenu-button first last"`. Given that added complexity, I think I'd best be handled by `merge` filter and break it out into it's own variable similar to how your doing it. I've updated my answer, WDYT?

Comment: @KendallHopkins you're damn right. +1 for you, i like your (second) approach in your edit. I would invert however `loop.first` and `loop-last` check, as the first and only element of an array should be considered and styled as first. But this is up to him.

Answer (score 4):

If it's to manage class attribut of a tag, a ternary condition would be better.

```
<span class="topmenu-button {{ (loop.first) ? 'first' : '' }}">{{ item.text }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in Drupal 8 views template. Thanks for 'elseif', if you have only 1 item, then the first item never get the 'last' class:

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {% set parity = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
    {% set row_classes = [ default_row_class ? 'views-row', ] %}    

    <div class="views-prerow {{parity}}{% if loop.first %} first{% elseif loop.last %} last{% endif %}">
        <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
            {{ row.content }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```